# Wordpress setup using EC2 Instance

Tags: linux, centos, wordpress

As of now I can visit the wordpress installer on the browser

But the problem is I having an error `504 Gateway Time out`

[image]

As I open the log file shown in the frontend this gaves multiple error like this

```
POST-EXTACT-CHECKS
--------------------------------------
PERMISSION UPDATES:
   -DIRS:  '755'
    -FILES: '644'
[PHP ERR][WARN] MSG:chmod(): Operation not permitted [CODE:2|FILE:/var/www/html/etha/dup-
installer/lib/snaplib/class.snaplib.u.io.php|LINE:479]
```

I've already made `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/projectwp` but seems nothing works

**UPDATE**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've similar issue like what you are faced.

Try this

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/projectwp
```

Comment: `sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /var/www/html/projectwp` tried this but still getting the 504 gateway

Comment: Im using CentOS

Answer (score 0):

Ah pardon me try this one then

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/projectwp
```

Or

```
sudo chgrp -R apache:apache /var/www/html/projectwp
```

References https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58157/what-is-the-equivalent-for-www-data-for-centos

Comment: I am still getting the error as I check the log file says most of the error are operation not permitted.  Check the update post